# IoT Central - How to Generate API token programatically

Tags: azure-iot-central

I wanted to use IoT Central REST API call.
But for using any REST API calls, we need an Authorization token.

So I want a way how we can create a new API Token in IoT Central programmatically.

From the below tutorial, found two ways :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-iot-central-apps-with-rest-api/2-authorize-api

1. In the Administration section in your application's web UI on the IoT Central portal.
2. Using the IoT Central REST API.

To generate an API token using the REST API, you must already have an Application administrator API token or a bearer token to authorize the call.

Now for getting bearer token, we have to use az cli which is not a feasible option for our approach. So instead of manually creating API token, we want a way to generate it programatically

Could you please give me some references on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bearer token is associated with an Azure Active Directory user account, therefore you need to be authenticated to retrieve it.

With the bearer token you can generate an IoT Central Api Token programatically. The REST **GET** call is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/apitokens/get

See also: [Authentication vs authorization doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)